# How to received ibeacons different regions ranging event in single didRangeBeacons:inRegion callback.

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, estimote

I'm trying to range iOS ibeacons with multiple regions and it works well.

But my problem is, if I range multiple regions `region1` and `region2`, I received two ranging event calls, `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` separately. (So, if I show the beacons list in tableview, it is flashing.)

I want to received all regions with different identifier in ranges into single `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` callback (not one callback for one region. one callback for all regions in range). I saw it can be done with Estimote's SDK by setting `estBeaconManager.returnAllRangedBeaconsAtOnce = YES;`.

I want to implement similar solution like estimote sdk did with iOS `CoreLocation`. Is there any solutions or sample code for this?

Comment: The only way I know of doing this is to combine them into a single region, using the same proximityUUID. The `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` does just what it says, tells you which beacons it ranged for *a given region*. Otherwise, you can write your own implementation that basically waits for all updates to come in for all regions and return them together at once.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to combine the two arrays of visible beacons into a single list.  You can do this by allocating an overall `NSMutableDictionary` in your `AppDelegate`'s `onCreate` method, then add beacons to this dictionary (keyed by UUID/major/minor) in the ranging callback method.

The tricky part is removing the beacons from your combined list when they are no longer visible.  The easiest way to do this is to keep a second `NSMutableDictionary` also keyed by UUID/major/minor, and storing an `NSDate` timestamp of when it was last seen.  When a beacon's last seen timestamp is more than five seconds in the past, remove the beacon's entrust from each  `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to keep an NSDictionary of CLBeacon objects and keep it synchronized each time the didRangeBeacons method is called.

It is important to understand that you each time the didRangeBeacons method is called, a new set of CLBeacon objects generated and returned that are not == to the previously returned CLBeacons. To handle this I would recommend storing your CLBeacons in an NSMutableDictionary with a unique ID that can be used to identify and compare multiple instances of CLBeacon that represent the same actual iBeacon. This way you can easily add/remove CLBeacons from the NSDictionary and keep it up to date, and with no duplicates after each time the didRangeBeacons is called.

Here is how to do it:

First create the dictionary in your CLLocationManager's delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *beaconsByUniqueID;
```

Next modify your didRangeBeacons method to merge each new set of CLBeacon objects into

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {

    if(!self.beaconsByUniqueID) {
        self.beaconsByUniqueID = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // This could also be done in your init
    }

    // Remove all CLBeacon objects for the CLBeaconRegion being returned
    NSMutableArray *uniqueIDsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.beaconsByUniqueID count]];
    for(NSString *beaconUniqueID in self.beaconsByUniqueID) {
        CLBeacon *beacon = [self.beaconsByUniqueID objectForKey:beaconUniqueID];
        if([beacon.proximityUUID isEqual:region.proximityUUID]) {     // Only remove Beacons in the currently returned region

            [uniqueIDsToRemove addObject:beaconUniqueID];
        }
    }
    [self.beaconsByUniqueID removeObjectsForKeys:uniqueIDsToRemove];

    // Add in the new beacon objects
    for(CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        [self.beaconsByUniqueID setObject:beacon forKey:[self uniqueIDForBeacon:beacon]];
    }

    // beaconsByUniqueID now contains the most recent set of iBeacons with no duplicates
    // Reload your tableView here
    // or call a custom callback with beaconsByUniqueID
}
```

Your uniqueIDForBeacon method can return any NSString that will be unique to the iBeacon. I would recommend simply combining the UUID, major, and minor values into one string to create a unique value for each iBeacon.

```
- (NSString *)uniqueIDForBeacon:(CLBeacon *)beacon {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString], beacon.major, beacon.minor];
}
```

You said that you want a single callback to do return all iBeacons. You could simply create a custom MYiBeaconManager object that implements the above code and calls a custom call to its delegate at the end of didRangeBeacons to tell the delegate that the iBeacon set was updated.