# Altbeacon library ranging is detecting a beacon only 30% of the time

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am using AltBeacon library to range beacons near my device. I am using all the default values of the library, that is 1100ms of scan period, and 0ms between scan periods.

The library is calling my listener every 1100ms, but the problem is that in a lot of this callings, there is no beacon detection. The beacon is only detected about 30%-40% of the callings, the other 70% of the callings says that there is no beacons around.

What can i do to solve this?

Regards

Comment: What type of beacon are you using?  What is its transmission frequency?  If the beacon is transmitting once every three seconds, this is what you would expect to see.

Comment: I am currently using Estimote Beacons. The default advertising interval of the beacon was 950 millseconds. I have changed it to 500milliseconds but i am having the same problem. I have tried with RECO beacons too.

Comment: Can you post your code that sets up ranging? What Android device model are you using for the test?

Comment: I am instantiating the beacon manager with something like this:  `mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(appContext);
mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
mBeaconManager.bind(this);
mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(aApplicationContext);
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD);
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);`  Then i start ranging like this:  `mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);`

Comment: Later i receive the events in the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` of my listener. I receive one call each second, but in lot of them, the `Collection<Beacon>` that is passed as an argument, is empty

Answer (score 5):

After reviewing a very large 50 second LogCat excerpt sent privately, I saw that two beacons were detected at irregular intervals:

```
Beacon #1 7383942b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx id2: 5 id3: 5000
   Max time between detections:   5.75600001 s
   Mean time between detections:  2.03854544 s
   % range cycles with detection: 51%

Beacon #2 b9407f30-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx id2: 60039 id3: 2279
   Max time between detections:   4.794999515 s
   Mean time between detections:  1.377583336 s
   % range cycles with detection: 82 %
```

The library code was starting and stopping bluetooth scans every 1100 ms as expected, and in 89% of the ranging cycles, at least one of the two beacons was detected.  This suggests that the app, library and operating system are all working properly -- there are no significant periods of time where no beacons aren't being detected.  What's more the RSSI of each beacon suggests a reasonably strong signal that is fairly consistent over the period of the log.  But the detection interval of the beacons is highly irregular.  This is unusual.

This suggests some radio or hardware issue, either with the beacons, the phone, or the radio environment.  A few possibilities:

1. The beacons really are not transmitting regularly, and actually do have dropouts. (This seems unlikely if you are using two different beacon models.)
2. The phone's bluetooth hardware has an issue that is causing it to miss a lot of bluetooth advertising packets (perhaps due to CRC errors), so the operating system, library and app never see them.
3. The testing is being done in a location with lots of radio noise, which is causing the CRC errors mentioned in possibility 2.

I think a problem with the Android device is the most likely of the possibilities, although I admit this is the first such case I have seen.  I would suggest that you try with a second Android device and see if you can reproduce the issue.  Because of the possibility that this is a hardware issue, it would be useful to document the device model you are using.

**EDIT:** The questioner sent additional information offline saying he was using a Nexus 5 with the 2.0-beta7 version of the library, and said the problem did not used to exist and only showed up when upgrading to this version of this library.   I did some additional tests myself with on a Nexus 5 and the 2.0-beta7 version of the library, modifying the [android-beacon-library-reference](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) app to add the following code on each ranging callback:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
        int rssi = -100;
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
            logToDisplay("Beacon "+beacon.toString()+" is about "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away, with Rssi: "+beacon.getRssi());
            if (beacon.getId1().toString().equals("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6") && beacon.getId2().toString().equals("1") && beacon.getId3().toString().equals("1")) {
                rssi = beacon.getRssi();
            }
        }
        if (rssi > -100) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: "+rssi);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon not found in ranging cycle");
        }

    }
}
```

I then turned on a RadBeacon USB transmitting with 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6/1/1 at 10Hz, and then looked at the debug output with the filter and results below.  As you can see, there was no cycle for the 60 seconds I ran the test where any beacons were not detected.

```
$ adb logcat -v time | grep "ranging cycle"

10-07 15:17:00.076 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:01.180 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -73
10-07 15:17:02.287 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -75
10-07 15:17:03.422 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:04.545 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:05.714 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:06.815 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:07.989 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -65
10-07 15:17:09.087 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -72
10-07 15:17:10.198 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -65
10-07 15:17:11.322 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -71
10-07 15:17:12.484 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:13.587 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -64
10-07 15:17:14.758 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:15.867 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:16.998 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:18.195 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:19.280 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:20.415 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:21.560 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:22.659 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:23.802 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:25.035 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -66
10-07 15:17:26.189 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:27.331 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -73
10-07 15:17:28.458 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:29.618 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -67
10-07 15:17:30.756 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -84
10-07 15:17:31.886 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -76
10-07 15:17:33.047 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -76
10-07 15:17:34.193 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -85
10-07 15:17:35.339 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -83
10-07 15:17:36.502 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -90
10-07 15:17:37.683 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -78
10-07 15:17:38.871 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -87
10-07 15:17:40.079 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -90
10-07 15:17:41.234 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -85
10-07 15:17:42.422 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -87
10-07 15:17:43.588 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -88
10-07 15:17:44.751 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -88
10-07 15:17:45.924 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -86
10-07 15:17:47.114 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -83
10-07 15:17:48.264 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -82
10-07 15:17:49.409 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -82
10-07 15:17:50.612 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -88
10-07 15:17:51.781 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -79
10-07 15:17:52.913 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -79
10-07 15:17:54.122 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -82
10-07 15:17:55.296 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -84
10-07 15:17:56.441 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -89
10-07 15:17:57.631 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -75
10-07 15:17:58.782 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -63
10-07 15:17:59.924 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -71
10-07 15:18:01.098 D/RangingActivity(16630): Beacon found in ranging cycle.  rssi: -72
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in depth analysis. I have been evaluating all the possibilities with my technical team, and we doubt that can be any of that 3. One person of my team , has done a very intensive analysis of beacons data with your library, and wants to talk with you about the problem. He has a lot of graphs that can show to you to describe his theory of the problem. Can i put him in contact with you? We are so interested on using AltBeacon but we must fix our problem :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, please contact us at support@radiusnetworks.com, and we can set up a time to speak.

Comment: I have added an additional edit to my answer above based on getting additional info offline.

Comment: But you are trying with an USB beacon, an at 10hz of frequency. We don't have a problem in this situation, we have problems with higher fequencies, like 600ms or more.

Comment: Yes, infrequently transmitting beacons will have their transmissions periodically missed, this is one of the reasons that the 10Hz rate has become the preferred standard.  There are several reasons for missing individual transmissions including radio noise and clock drift, which cause CRC errors that cause the hardware to reject advertisement packets.  A certain percentage of packets always get rejected.

Comment: If you need to use infrequently transmitting beacons, then you must design your software to accept missing seeing beacons in individual ranging callbacks. You can use a technique like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26106879/1461050

Comment: But when we were using the previous version of the library, previous to be named AltBeacon, a 0.XX version, i don't remember to be loosing frames. Is this possible=

Comment: To my knowledge (and I am the primary author of both library versions), there is no difference in the way scanning works between these versions.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After seeing a log excerpt, I have submitted a second answer.

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Try repeating this test with WiFi disabled on your Android device. Some Android devices have combined WiFi/Bluetooth components that interfere with each other when in simultaneous use.
2. Make sure it is not a hardware issue.  Try using a known working scanner like an iOS device with the Locate app installed or the [Android Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) (using your same custom beacon parser expression) and see if you see the same behavior.

Comment: 1. Yes, all my tests have been done without wifi, because i had problems with that on the past.

2. I have installed Android Locate App, and if i enter in the detail of a beacon, i see a lot of "non detected", and i see it during various seconds. 

¿Is this normal?

Comment: With my iOS version of the app, this is not happening, everything is working ok

Comment: Sorry you are having trouble.  Would it be possible for you to capture some log output from your app?  To get debug level log output from the library, add a line of code like: `beaconManager.setDebug(true);`  Then capture the LogCat output during the time you get intermittent beacon detections -- one minute or more would be best.  The log excerpt will be long, so please send it to support@radiusnetworks.com.  I will review and summarize any issues I see in a response in this forum without posting any identifiers or other private info.

Comment: Ok David, i have sent it. THANKS! ;)

Comment: Hi David, did you receive the log?